# How do i import FBA users to a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, forms-authentication

I have configure Forms Based Authentication Users in my SharePoint site and its working fine im actually able to register new users. I now need to show these users on my homepage as newly registered users. So i want to import these users into a SharePoint list and show them as a custom web part on a page

Answer (score 1):

You can use this webpart available on codeplex to do any operation with users created for FBA Authenthication

[SharePoint 2013 FBA Pack](https://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/)

> This forms based authentication pack is for SharePoint 2013. It
>   includes web parts for *registering users*, *changing passwords* and
>   *password recovery*. It includes tools for managing users and roles and for approving registrations.

All operations are done in SharePoint list so you will get newly created users easily in your webpart using **Created Date**